# Add Custom Endpoint URL to WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, endpoint

I m working on inserting custom Endpoint into "My Account" page in [WooCommerce page](http://touchdowner.cz/digitalni-produkty), but dont know how to point to Change Password page. I used this code into functions:

```
function wpb_woo_my_account_order() {
 $myorder = array(
 'downloads' => __( 'Objednávky', 'woocommerce' ),
 'edit-address' => __( 'Adresa', 'woocommerce' ),
 'edit-account' => __( 'Detaily účtu', 'woocommerce' ),
 '/author/' . $current_user->display_name . '?edit_info' => __( 'Změnit 
 heslo', 'woocommerce' ),
 'customer-logout' => __( 'Odhlášení', 'woocommerce' ),
  );
  return $myorder;
 }
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'wpb_woo_my_account_order' );
```

In "Změnit heslo" endpoint i want to point to

```
/author/' . $current_user->display_name . '?edit_info
```

because that is URL to change password , but seems that is not working properly.

Comment: This is not a answer on question i requested. i dont ask for Tabbed My Account.

Comment: This question is related to endpoint on tabbed my account… An endpoint is an URL too! … You can't set an end point URL using `woocommerce_account_menu_items` filter hook… It's a bit more complicated!